# not getting mail from Java application using smtp

Tags: java, smtp

I have a java application which send mail using SMTP,but recently a modified its  property file and restarted my tomcat server [although property change is a password change and is not related to smtp  ].
now it is not sending mails :(

I checked my smtp server and tried to send mail from it.It is sending.
Any idea what went wrong?

any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: and please tell me how to know that my request from application reaches the smtp server or not

Comment: Can you share the Tomcat logs (or any other logs you use)? There should be some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SMTP server logs should tell you whether something was sent to it, and why it didn't relay the email.
If your change was password related, an authentication error may be the cause.

I would look at the following first:
Which credentials is your Java application using to send requests to the SMTP server?

Then, are these credentials still accepted on the server?

Finally, most SMTP servers will have a separate list of either included or excluded source IPs, from where to accept message requests, see if your Java app's source machine is allowed there.

Comment: Thanks everyone!! :) looking at tomcat log i got the error and issue.It was invalid email id that was causing exception...thanks a lot Anton M